# Keeping branches in sync with frequent deployments

Tags: git, development-environment, continuous-deployment, git-flow, continuous-delivery

In my company, we have a requirement to deploy whenever a feature branch is ready to go live - no waiting around. For this purpose, I've came up with with this dev/gitflow process:

[image: Our dev process]

The process will work like so:

1. A developer branches off the "release" branch and works on the feature branch.
2. While working, the developer can do a local test on `dev` by merging into it. It is like staging, but QA doesn't touch this environment.
3. When the developer tests locally and completes work, they merge it into our `staging` branch and issue a Pull Request into the `release` branch. [Green line #1]
4. Once on the `staging` branch, the staging server automatically gets updated and QA tests on it. [Green line #2]
5. If QA approves it, they accept the Pull Request and everything that's been tested should now be in the `release` branch. [Dotted green line]
6. As soon as the `release` branch gets a change, we merge it into the `master` (Production) branch and do a deploy.
7. **My question: After deploying into production, would we merge `production` back into `staging` and `dev`? [Red lines]**

My concern is that this process would cause a lot of code conflicts when merging `production` back downward. Especially if we have stuff on staging that is being moved around from QA -> dev -> QA over and over.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of noise in this flow and my concern is that it's overcomplicating what [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) nominally accomplishes.  My advice in general is to simplify this flow as much as possible - if you need a separate "staging" branch then create it - but in general:

- Production-ready code lives in master.
- Developers base work off of master.  They can test their feature branch *locally*, and if they can't, that's something that should be fixed sooner rather than later.
- Feature branches that require QA testing gets pushed to staging.  Ideally, only one feature at a time exists here unless QA agrees to handle more.
- After staging is tested to satisfaction, then that is merged to master and released into production.

Given that the likelihood of occurrence of multiple feature branches being ready at *exactly* the same time is rare, simplifying the release cycle in this fashion so that no ambiguity exists with QA (in that it's only ever testing the one feature branch at a time) would simplify things a lot.

Comment: Agree with this. We considered "environment centric" branches, like `dev`, `qa`, `stage`, but decided against it. Doing so would move too far away fro `git-flow`, which has served us well, and mean that the entire flow (basically amounting to building an alternative to git flow from the ground up) would need to be scripted / perfected by us (no easy task).